# Request new work network on Facebook

Tags: facebook

Any idea how to request Facebook to create a network for my employer?  It's a small company (50-ish people).

The [existing Facebook question](http://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1165471) on this has several suggested options, none of which seem to work anymore.

Comment: have you tried the options ? a lot of people tend to make useless/fake networks so their confirmation may not necessarily equate to yours.

Comment: What makes this a particular problem is that my account has been tagged as belonging to a network from a business I worked at ten years ago when FB first opened up to allow businesses in. Now I can't get rid of this obsolete network -- FB requires you to add a network first before deleting an old one, and I simply have no FB-valid networks). Nor can I join a network for our (newer) company because you can't add new networks. As someone else remarked, it's amazing that there is no FB support for these forums; we're left to speculate and thrash around on our own.

Comment: @Mac McCarthy - facebook isn't 10 years old :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can Google, Facebook is not currently making new networks. [All](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1315762) of the [discussions](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1261004) I've [seen](https://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=14507320155&topic=7065) suggest that Facebook isn't responding to new network requests anymore (or even talking about networks for long enough to confirm that!).

This makes some sense from the point of view of our Facebook overlords if you consider the fact that networks used to be the primary way to decide how much information you shared with whom. In bygone days, you could share information with friends, friends-of-friends, or your whole network. Now, the options are friends, friends-of-friends, everyone, or "customize" - in which you get to pick specific people who can see your post. The main purpose of a network has been "phased out", and I wouldn't be surprised if networks disappear entirely in the next year or two.

The other function of networks - to group people who go to the same school or work for the same company - has been replaced by "fan pages" that are connected to your profile when you [enter where you work or go to school](https://www.facebook.com/editprofile.php?sk=eduwork).

[*n.b.: this is all conjecture on my part. But it seems to make some sense, don't it?*]

Answer (score 6):

Facebook has listed their "no" [answer here](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=181740841907829#Can-I-create-a-new-network?).

A member of Facebook's Developer Relations team for EMEA (?), Colm Doyle [confirms (on Quora no less!)](http://www.quora.com/Facebook-1/How-can-I-create-a-network-for-my-college-on-Facebook):

> We no longer accept requests to create networks. You can setup a public group though.

Comment: EMEA = Europe, Middle East and Africa, it that's why you put the question mark,